# Prove that if $\int_a^\infty g(x) dx$ is convergent then $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

where $f$ and $g$ are positive continuous functions on $[a, \infty)$, and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

I tried to prove this as follows:

[image: proof]

But something tells me I can't do the bottom-left part, or that I'm missing some parts, or that my logic might be flawed altogether.

Thanks :)

Comment: Image missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be wrong that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)\to0$, but it could be that $g(x)$ grows faster than $f(x)$, and so maybe that's why $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to0$. So, it's not a flaw in logic - it's just that you are removing other plausible situations.

Comment: So $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ will _necessarily_ be less than $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$, but not necessarily 0? Which makes $f(x)$ also bounded.

Comment: @SammiFernandez Not necessary - $f(x)$ need not be bounded in the general case: Try showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{e^x}\to0$ (maybe by L'Hopital's rule and using the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x\to\infty$), but $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\to\infty,$ so $f(x)=x$ is not bounded. Also, $\lim_{x→∞}f(x)$ will necessarily be less than $\lim_{x→∞}g(x)$ for large $x$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an $r\ge a$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\le 1 \quad \forall x \ge r.
$$
It follows that
$$
0\le \int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx\le \int_a^rf(x)\,dx+\int_r^\infty g(x)\,dx<\infty.
$$